# I am having trouble with if statements and possibly a def function

Tags: python-3.x

So when running the code, it works as intended except for the fact that when looped a second time, the if statement doesn't work. May I ask for some help please.

```
cart=[]
price_total=[]
stuff={"potato": 50, "apple": 35, "orange": 40, "banana": 25, "popcorn": 120, "water": 20, "cola": 
40}
y=1       


def main():
  print("Thanks for using checkout")
  print("(1) make a transaction")
  customer_input=int(input("What would you like to do:"))



main()
if customer_input==1:
  print("potato=50") 
  print("apple=35")
  print("orange=40")
  print("banana=25")
  print("popcorn=120")
  print("water=20")
  print("cola=40")
  global order_input
  order_input=input("What would you like to order:")
  cart.append(order_input)
  lol()
```

Comment: can you add some details about how you run this, or the code of the loop? moreover, a traceback of the error would be useful.

Comment: what is `lol()`?

Comment: What do you mean by your statement " when looped a second time, the if statement doesn't work"?  How are you looping the second time?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to implement what you want to do.

- Using Functions, which is the approach you seem to be trying to implement
- Using classes, which would be a more Object oriented approach

### The Functional Approach

In the functional approach all operations are managed by individual functions, and many of the essential variables are passed to these functions.  Here are the implemented functions:

```
# The Functional Approach
def getInput(prompt, respType= None):
    """Simple Function To Gather input and verify it's type,
       Returns the User input converted to the requested type
       if it is consistent with the type specifier"""
    while True:
        resp = input(prompt)
        if respType == str or respType == None:
            break
        else:
            try:
                resp = respType(resp)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input, please try again')
    return resp

def list_stock(inv):
    """Returns a printable list of all items currently in inventory """
    kylist = sorted(list(inv.keys()))
    s = "The Items currently in stock include:\n"
    for i in range(len(kylist)):
            s += f'{i+1:4}\t{kylist[i]:10} {inv[kylist[i]]} each\n'
    return s  

def add_to_cart(item, qty, cart):
    """Adds Item to cart and returns updated cart"""
    cdi = cart.pop(item, 0)
    cdi += qty
    cart[item] = cdi
    return cart

def contents(cart, inv):
    """Returns printable list of cart contents"""
    ckys = cart.keys()
    s = "The Items currently in your cart include:\n"
    s += 'Item\tQty\tCost\n'
    for ky in ckys:
        qty = cart[ky]
        cost= qty* inv[ky]
        s += f'{ky}\t{qty}\t{cost}\n'
    return s

def total_bill(cart, inv):
    """Returns the Total Cost of items in Cart"""
    total = 0
    for itm, qty in cart.items():
        total += qty*inv[itm]
    return total

def load_cart(cart, inv):
    stock = sorted(list(inv.keys()))
    print(list_stock(inv))
    while True:
        itm = stock[getInput('Please enter an item number to add to your cart', int)-1]
        qty = getInput(f'please enter the number of {itm} you want added to your cart', int)
        add_to_cart(itm, qty, cart)
        if  getInput("Do you have more to add? (y/n)").lower() != 'y':    
                break
```

The main function which then controls process flow and manages calling necessary functions includes:

```
# The Main Method for Functional Appraoch
stuff={"potato": 50, "apple": 35, "orange": 40, "banana": 25, "popcorn": 120, "water": 20, "cola": 
40}
cart = dict()
print("Thanks for using checkout")
while True:
    if getInput('Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N)').lower()[0]  == 'y':
        load_cart(cart, stuff)
        print(contents(cart, stuff))
        print (f'Your total bill = {total_bill(cart, stuff)}' )       
    else:
        print('Have a nice day!')
        break
```

A typical execution of this main routine would look like:

```
Thanks for using checkout
Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N) y
The Items currently in stock include:
   1    apple      35 each
   2    banana     25 each
   3    cola       40 each
   4    orange     40 each
   5    popcorn    120 each
   6    potato     50 each
   7    water      20 each

Please enter an item number to add to your cart 3
please enter the number of cola you want added to your cart 2
Do you have more to add? (y/n) n
The Items currently in your cart include:
Item    Qty Cost
cola    2   80

Your total bill = 80
Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N) n
Have a nice day!
```

### A more Object Oriented Approach

In the OO approach, many of the basic operations are implemented as methods within a Cart Class.  Using the Cart Class groups methods together and keeps them associated with the cart.  The following gives an implementation using the Cart Class.

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, inventory):
        self._cart = dict()
        self._inv = inventory
        
    def in_inventory(self, item):
        return item in self._inv.keys()
    
    @property
    def stock(self):
        return sorted(list(self._inv.keys()))
    
    def price(self, itm):
        return self._inv[itm]

    @property
    def inventory(self):
        kylist = self.stock
        s = "The Items currently in stock include:\n"
        for i in range(len(kylist)):
                s += f'{i+1:4}\t{kylist[i]:10} {self._inv[kylist[i]]} each\n'
        return s
    
    def add_to_cart(self, item, qty= 1):
        cdi = self._cart.pop(item, 0)
        cdi += qty
        self._cart[item] = cdi
        
    @property
    def contents(self):
        ckys = self._cart.keys()
        s = "The Items currently in your cart include:\n"
        s += 'Item\tQty\tCost\n'
        for ky in ckys:
            qty = self._cart[ky]
            cost= qty* self._inv[ky]
            s += f'{ky}\t{qty}\t{cost}\n'
        return s
 
    @property
    def bill(self):
        total = 0
        for itm, qty in self._cart.items():
            total += qty*self.price(itm)
        return total
```

Using the Cart Class for most of the needed methods, leaves only 1 separate function

```
def load_cart(cart):
    stock = cart.stock
    print(cart.inventory)
    while True:
        itm = stock[getInput('Please enter an item number to add to your cart', int)-1]
        qty = getInput(f'please enter the number of {itm} you want added to your cart', int)
        cart.add_to_cart(itm, qty)
        if  getInput("Do you have more to add? (y/n)").lower() != 'y':    
                break
```

The main function which manages the entire application would then look like:

```
# The main routine to execute the Object Oriented Appraoch
stuff={"potato": 50, "apple": 35, "orange": 40, "banana": 25, "popcorn": 120, "water": 20, "cola": 
40}
cart = Cart(stuff)
print("Thanks for using checkout")
while True:
    if getInput('Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N)').lower()[0]  == 'y':
        load_cart(cart)
        print(cart.contents)
        print (f'Your total bill = {cart.bill}' )       
    else:
        print('Have a nice day!')
        break
```

Executing this Main method would produce results like:

```
Thanks for using checkout
Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N) y
The Items currently in stock include:
   1    apple      35 each
   2    banana     25 each
   3    cola       40 each
   4    orange     40 each
   5    popcorn    120 each
   6    potato     50 each
   7    water      20 each

Please enter an item number to add to your cart 4
please enter the number of orange you want added to your cart 3
Do you have more to add? (y/n) n
The Items currently in your cart include:
Item    Qty Cost
orange  3   120

Your total bill = 120
Would you like to load a cart? (Y/N) n
Have a nice day!
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your code under def main() and use main() just call the the function.  You can then use while loops to keep asking for user input and provide a way for user to exit by entering -1 or something similar:

```
cart=[]
price_total=0
stuff={"potato": 50, "apple": 35, "orange": 40, "banana": 25, "popcorn": 120, "water": 20, "cola":40}
y=1

def main():
    global price_total
    print("Thanks for using checkout")
    print("(1) make a transaction. (-1) to exit.")
    customer_input = int(input("What would you like to do: "))
    while customer_input == 1:
      print("potato=50")
      print("apple=35")
      print("orange=40")
      print("banana=25")
      print("popcorn=120")
      print("water=20")
      print("cola=40")
      global order_input
      order_input = input("What would you like to order? (-1) to finish: ")
      if order_input == "-1":
          print(f'You bought {cart} for total price of {price_total}.')
          break
      cart.append(order_input)
      price_total += stuff[order_input]

main()
```